# Android java takes time until the application returns from the camera

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, parse-platform

I have the onActivityResult function (After capture a picture) and the function run in the camera intent. That is to say I didnt see the ProgressDialog becase its run on camera intent and its loading a lot of time.
How can I do that first the app will return from camera intents and then run the onActivityResult function?

```
Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "POST_IMAGE.jpg");
                            chooserIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                            imageToUploadUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
                            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 1220);
```

The function:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1220 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {


        final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(PageAndExercise.this);
        mDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mDialog.show();

        Uri selectedImage = imageToUploadUri;
        getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
        Bitmap reducedSizeBitmap = getBitmap(imageToUploadUri.getPath());
        if(reducedSizeBitmap != null) {



            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            reducedSizeBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            //  bookimage.setImageBitmap(photo);
            byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();
            ParseFile file = new ParseFile("photo.jpeg", image);
            file.saveInBackground();


            ParseObject toaccept = new ParseObject("Answers");

            toaccept.put("Picture", file);


            try {
               toaccept.save();
} catch (ParseException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getString(R.string.error),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move everything after `mDialog.show()` into a background thread. Do not do disk I/O, data parsing, and the like on the main application thread.

Then, replace `mDialog.show()` with a `DialogFragment` to manage your `ProgressDialog`, so you handle configuration changes (e.g., screen rotation) properly.

Comment: Thanks! but I get error: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5 java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()  In the line   AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialog2.create(); alertDialog2.show();

Comment: @Ron: There is no such code in your question. If you have a *new* crash with *new* code, ask a *new* question where you post the *new* code and the *new* stack trace, so that *new* people can examine your *new* question and give you *new* answers.